# Firebase function exception when onCall Http

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: Response is not valid JSON object.

```
    exports.loadVideos = functions
  .region('asia-south1')
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    let uid = []

    const subscribers = await db
      .collection(SUBSCRIPTIONS_COLLECTION)
      .doc('05piDSvu5mNxHOn2yKpnL2V322r1')
      .get()
    subscribers.data().subsBy.forEach((s) => {
      uid.push(s.userId)
    })

    return db
      .collection('videos')
      .where('userId', 'not-in', uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          return res.status(404).send({
            error: 'Unable to find the document',
          })
        }
        let items = []
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          items.push(doc.data())
        })
        return res.status(200).send(items)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
        return res.status(404).send({
          error: 'Unable to retrieve the document',
          err,
        })
      })
  })
```

Unable to find out issue, it's working well when trying with single text but I need whole collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u send items array in response directly, it will throw Exception.

There are some rules ref [Medium Article](https://csiandal.medium.com/firebase-function-error-response-is-missing-data-field-2c27768e0bd) to follow.

As of Exception, there is no valid JSON object. You have to convert your items array to an Object and pass in response followed by key "data" :

**Wrong**  `return res.status(200).send(items)`

**Right**   `return res.status(200).send({ data: { items } })`

Answer (score 1):

Callable Cloud Functions can only return JSON types. You can't return an entire `QuerySnapshot`, which is what your code is trying to do.

If you want to return the data of the documents, that'd be:

```
return { videos: filteredVideo.map((doc) => doc.data()) }
```

If you also want to return the document ID of each document, that'd be:

```
const result = filteredVideo.map((doc) => {
  return { id: doc.id, data: doc.data() }
})
return { videos: result }
```

Comment: tried it now getting NOT_FOUND EXCEPTION

Comment: code is updated, please review it again

Comment: I had tested this code on emulator, it is working fine